# PySpark dataframe column to list

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to extract the list of column values from a dataframe into a list

```
+------+----------+------------+
|sno_id|updt_dt   |process_flag|
+------+----------+------------+
| 123  |01-01-2020|     Y      |
+------+----------+------------+
| 234  |01-01-2020|     Y      |
+------+----------+------------+
| 512  |01-01-2020|     Y      |
+------+----------+------------+
| 111  |01-01-2020|     Y      |
+------+----------+------------+
```

Output should be the list of sno_id ['123','234','512','111']
Then I need to iterate the list to run some logic on each on the list values. I am currently using HiveWarehouseSession to fetch data from hive table into Dataframe by using hive.executeQuery(query)

Comment: what logic are you trying to run on the list values? and are you grouping with process_flag or updt_dt or both?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it is pretty easy as you can first collect the df with will return list of Row type then

```
row_list = df.select('sno_id').collect()
```

then you can iterate on row type to convert column into list

```
sno_id_array = [ row.sno_id for row in row_list]

sno_id_array 
['123','234','512','111']
```

**Using Flat map and more optimized solution**

```
sno_id_array = df.select("sno_id ").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Comment: I got ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'collect'```, so instead of ```sno_id_array = [ row.sno_id for row in row_list .collect()]``` use ```sno_id_array = [ row.sno_id for row in row_list]```

Comment: how come the rdd flatmap is more optimal?

Comment: If you notice in first method we collecting the dataframe and then iterating each value, while in second way we dont require to do that we directly iterate on rdd

Comment: Is it a good approach when we are talking about millions of distinct values? The `rdd` one.

Comment: @Debuggerrr Not at all... Try to avoid rdd as much as possible in pyspark.  Otherwise you will be doing most of your computations on the driver node, which defeats the purpose of distributed computing. You might as well just run in on your laptop then.

Comment: Understood brother 

Answer (score -1):

You could use `toLocalIterator()` to create a generator containing all rows in the column:

```py
sno_ids = df.select('sno_id').toLocalIterator()
for row in sno_ids:
    sno_id = row.sno_id
    # continue with your logic
    ...
```

Alternative one-liner using a generator expression:

```py
sno_ids = (row.sno_id for row in df.select('sno_id').toLocalIterator())
for sno_id in sno_ids:
    ...
```

Since you want to loop over the results afterwards this may be more efficient.
Using a generator you don't create and store the list upfront, but you fetch the results while iterating over the rows. However:

> The iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in this DataFrame. With prefetch it may consume up to the memory of the 2 largest partitions. -- [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toLocalIterator.html)